# Disabling Future Dates bootstrap vue datepicker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap-vue plugin. I want to disable future date for bootstrap-vue datepicker.

Here is my code:

```
<b-form-datepicker :date-disabled-fn="disabledDates" v-model="form.date_of_birth" placeholder="Select Date"/>
```

And in Js part:

```
methods: {
      dateDisabled(ymd, date) {
        // Disable weekends (Sunday = `0`, Saturday = `6`) and
        // disable days that fall on the 13th of the month
        const weekday = date.getDay()
        const day = date.getDate()
        // Return `true` if the date should be disabled
        return weekday === 0 || weekday === 6 || day === 13
      }
    }
```

It is disabling weekends & 13th of month. But I want to disable all future date.

According to their documentation:

```
The function should either return true if the date cannot be selected (disabled), or false if the date can be selected (enabled). Note that the function cannot be asynchronous, and should return a value as quickly as possible.
```

I can not make the logic to return future date. How can I do this?

Comment: Per documentation - Minimum and maximum dates
Restrict the calendar range via the min and max props. The props accept a date string in the format of YYYY-MM-DD or a Date object.

Comment: Got it. It solve my problems. Thanks

Comment: This seems out of date, but the tag attribute yields to "disabledDates" but the method supposed to be called is called "dateDisabled". Don't they need to match? If I remember correctly there is also an attribute for "max" and "min" dates to be displayed/selecatable.